# HTML parsing with soup

Tags: python, html

I am trying to parse the stock split data out of this html table which is of itself part of a much larger web page but I don't see any id tags that I could specify with

```
split_rows = soup.select("xxxx#yyyy")[0].find_all("tr")
```

Any help much appreciated. My html knowledge is pretty low. The source is https://www.stocksplithistory.com/?symbol=ibm

```
</table>
</font></td>
<td width="18"><img src="/tpixel.gif" width="18" height="18"></td>
<td width="208" valign="top" bgcolor="#f6f6f6"><table border="0" width="208" 
style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <TD align="center" colspan="2" class="menuoff" style="border-right: 1px 
solid #CCCE05; border-left: 1px solid #CCCE05; border-top: 2px solid 
#000000; border-bottom: 2px solid #000000; text-transform: none" 
valign="middle" align="left"><b>IBM Split History</b> Table</TD></TR>
    <tr><td align="center" width="65%" style="padding: 6px; background- 
color: #EEEEEE; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC"><i><b>Date</b></i></td>
    <td align="center" width="35%" style="padding: 6px; background-color: 
#EEEEEE; border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC"><i><b>Ratio</b></i></td></tr>
    <TR><TD align="center" style="padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px solid 
#CCCCCC">05/18/1964</TD><TD align="center" style="padding: 4px; border- 
bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC">5 for 4
</TD></TR><TR><TD align="center" style="padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px 
solid #CCCCCC">05/18/1966</TD><TD align="center" style="padding: 4px; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC">3 for 2
</TD></TR><TR><TD align="center" style="padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px 
solid #CCCCCC">04/23/1968</TD><TD align="center" style="padding: 4px; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC">2 for 1
</TD></TR><TR><TD align="center" style="padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px 
solid #CCCCCC">05/29/1973</TD><TD align="center" style="padding: 4px; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC">5 for 4
</TD></TR><TR><TD align="center" style="padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px 
solid #CCCCCC">06/01/1979</TD><TD align="center" style="padding: 4px; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC">4 for 1
</TD></TR><TR><TD align="center" style="padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px 
solid #CCCCCC">05/28/1997</TD><TD align="center" style="padding: 4px; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC">2 for 1
</TD></TR><TR><TD align="center" style="padding: 4px; border-bottom: 1px 
solid #CCCCCC">05/27/1999</TD><TD align="center" style="padding: 4px; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC">2 for 1
</TD></TR>
```

Comment: no one knows what you mean by "stock split data" ... what are you hoping to get as a result of your parsing this specific input and why? ... why use beautiful soup at all? `splits = re.findall("\d+ for \d+",text)` https://repl.it/repls/FondStrangeStructure

Comment: If you would like to locate that specific table, I would recommend identifying the `<b>IBM Split History</b>` tag and using something along the lines of `find_parent('table')` to locate the parent table. Unfortunately I can't test at work.

Comment: thanks I am trying to extract the date and "x for y" type data fields that detail the equity stock splits for each ticker

Answer (score 0):

You can find that table by its attributes

```
soup.find('table', attrs={'border': '0', 'width': '208', 'style':'font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px'})
```